# Set custom directory in theme for page templates

Tags: themes, hooks, page-template

I have a directory structure in my theme like this:

```
src/
  templates/
    pages/
      - faqs.php
    views/
      - page.php
```

In my custom functions I have a hook that tells WordPress to look in the `src/templates/views` directory for basic templates like `page.php`, etc. This works fine.

**What I would like to do is tell WordPress to look in `src/templates/pages` for any custom page templates**. From what I understand, WordPress scans the theme directory structure for any page templates but it only goes one-level deep.

For example, my `faqs.php` file has a template name of FAQs:

```php
<?php
/*
  Template Name: FAQs
*/
?>
```

If I move `faqs.php` to the `src` directory it appears in the WP Admin as an available option in the Template dropdown. But when I move it back to `src/templates/pages` it is no longer registered.

I have looked for a variety of solutions but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. It seemed like the [theme_page_templates hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) might be the answer, but I don't want to have to create the names of the template files in the select list, etc. I would prefer to just tell WordPress where to look and then let WP handle the rest from there. Not sure if that is possible though.

Comment: Are you aware of the top level `home.php` template? A page template is unnecessary

Comment: Yes, sorry, perhaps a bad example of a use case. I want to be able to put ALL my custom page templates in `src/templates/pages` and have them appear as custom page template options in the WP admin. (As opposed to having to put them all at the root of the theme directory or in a subfolder that's just one-level deep.)

Comment: Updated the example with a more generic custom page template example.